# Deleting DB records which are not in .csv file - efficiency?

Tags: php, mysql, oop, csv

I'm currently working on a .csv import which imports agenda items (such as events) and places them in a MySQL database. I've got the gist of it working, there is however a troublesome piece of code which I can't seem to wrap my head around on how to fix it or make it more efficient/better.

The part of code which is troublesome for me is when a event is held every -lets say- `tuesday` and `sunday` from `2012-06-01` 'till `2013-04-01` and you want to check if some of these values are allready in the DB (because a user might import the .csv file again with some adjusted values). My current code eventually implements the correct values in to the DB, but the way it is done is kind of a hassle. If the file gets imported again all values from sunday get deleted again because my check goes through a foreach on tuesday first, where it will check if the DB values match with the values generated for tuesday. After the checks are done and the values are inserted into the DB my foreach checks all values for sunday (tuesday does not get deleted because I keep an array with all previous inserted values) and then inserts them again.
So basically when I import a .csv file it removes and then inserts the same values, and my question is how would I prevent this?

Also, if you see any way to improve this code at all (because I really feel it's not efficient to begin with in the first place) please say so, it's much appreciated.

Here is the code that checks for the repetition of events, if you need any clarfication or other code please let me know:

```
//REPEAT DAYS OF THE WEEK
if(!empty($repeatDayOfTheWeek) && $repeatDayOfTheWeek != '')
{
    $daysOfTheWeek = explode(',', $repeatDayOfTheWeek);

    foreach($daysOfTheWeek as $key => $dayOfTheWeek)
    {
        if(!is_numeric($dayOfTheWeek))
        {
            continue;
        }

        unset($agendaI->agendaItemValues['stopDate']);

        $beginDate = strtotime($tempStartDate);
        $endDate = strtotime($tempStopDate);

        $dayDates = array();
        $arrayDatesInDb = array();

        if(!isset($previousInserts))
        {
            $previousInserts = array();
        }

        if($beginDate != '' && $endDate != '')
        {
            while($beginDate <= $endDate)
            {
                if(date('N', $beginDate) == $dayOfTheWeek)
                {
                    $dayDates[] = date('Y-m-d', $beginDate);
                }

                $beginDate = strtotime("+1 day", $beginDate);
            }

        $datesInDb = $agendaI->getAgendaItemsByExternId($externId);

        if(empty($datesInDb))
        {
            foreach($dayDates as $dayDate)
            {
                dump("Empty DB - INSERT: ".$dayDate);
                $agendaI->setAgendaItemValue('startDate', $dayDate);
                $agendaI->saveAgendaItem();
                $previousInserts[] = $dayDate;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            dump('DB with records');
            foreach($datesInDb as $dateInDb)
            {
                if(!in_array($dateInDb->startDate, $dayDates) && !in_array($dateInDb->startDate, $previousInserts))
                {
                    dump("Not in Item-array, but in DB - DELETE: ".$dateInDb->startDate);
                    $agendaI->deleteAgendaItem($dateInDb->id);
                }
            }

        foreach($dayDates as $dayDate)
        {
            foreach($datesInDb as $dateInDb)
            {
                if($dayDate == $dateInDb->startDate)
                {
                    $arrayDatesInDb[] = $dateInDb->startDate;
                    dump("In array & in DB - UPDATE: ".$dateInDb->startDate);
                    $agendaI->setAgendaItemValue('id', $dateInDb->id);
                    $agendaI->saveAgendaItem();
                    $previousInserts[] = $dayDate;
                }
            }
        }

    unset($agendaI->agendaItemValues['id']);

    foreach($dayDates as $dayDate)
    {
        if(!in_array($dayDate, $arrayDatesInDb))
        {
            dump("Not in DB-array but in Item-array - INSERT: ".$dayDate);
            $agendaI->setAgendaItemValue('startDate', $dayDate);
            $agendaI->saveAgendaItem();
            $previousInserts[] = $dayDate;
        }
    }
}
```

The following fields are in the .csv:

```
"Datum" "Tijdstip" "Evenement" "Locatie" "Website" "Toelichting" "Duits" "engels" "startdatum" "stopdatum" "herhalen dag van de week" "externid" "categorie" "via"
```

**in other words**
I need to check if the records in the DB are the same as in the .csv. If the csv does not have a record that the DB has I need to delete it from the DB (which my current code does, just not very efficient)

Comment: Might I ask the reason for the downvote?

Comment: @ the downvoters, could you provide a comment so I at least know what is "lacking research effort/unclear/not useful"? Thanks

Comment: To be clear, you're looking to replace a record that exists in the table if the CSV contains a new record with the *same* `startdatum`, `stopdatum` and `herhalen dag van de week`?

Comment: @eggyal Yes, there are however other values that might have changed. But that is not the reason for my question, the reason is _"So basically when I import a .csv file it removes and then inserts the same values, and my question is how would I prevent this?"_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually solved it in the following way without using a foreach for each $daysoftheweek and using array_diff:

```
            //REPEAT DAYS OF THE WEEK
            if(!empty($repeatDayOfTheWeek) && $repeatDayOfTheWeek != '')
            {
                $daysOfTheWeek = explode(',', $repeatDayOfTheWeek);

                $agendaI->setAgendaItemValue('stopDate', '');

                $beginDate = strtotime($startDate);
                $endDate = strtotime($stopDate);
                $dayDates = array();
                $dbValues = array();
                $dbValues['datum'] = array();
                $latestDbValues = array();
                $toBeDeletedKeys = array();

                while($beginDate <= $endDate)
                {
                    if(in_array(date('N', $beginDate), $daysOfTheWeek))
                    {
                        $dayDates[] = date('Y-m-d', $beginDate);
                    }

                    $beginDate = strtotime("+1 day", $beginDate);
                }

                $evenementenInDb = $agendaI->getAgendaItemsByExternId($externId);

                if(!empty($evenementenInDb))
                {
                    foreach($evenementenInDb as $evenementInDb)
                    {
                        $dbValues['agendaid'][] = $evenementInDb->id;
                        $dbValues['datum'][] = $evenementInDb->startDate;
                    }
                }

                foreach($dayDates as $dayDate)
                {
                    $key = array_search($dayDate, $dbValues['datum']); 
                    if($key !== false && is_numeric($key))
                    {
                        //UPDATE
                        $agendaI->setAgendaItemValue('id', $dbValues['agendaid'][$key]);
                        $agendaI->setAgendaItemValue('startDate', $dayDate);
                        $agendaI->saveAgendaItem();
                        $latestDbValues[] = $dayDate;
                        dump('UPDATE');
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //INSERT
                        unset($agendaI->agendaItemValues['id']);
                        $agendaI->setAgendaItemValue('startDate', $dayDate);
                        $agendaI->saveAgendaItem();
                        $latestDbValues[] = $dayDate;
                        dump('INSERT');
                    }
                }

                $toBeDeleted = array_diff($dbValues['datum'], $latestDbValues);
                foreach($toBeDeleted as $value)
                {
                    $toBeDeletedKeys[] = array_search($value, $dbValues['datum']);
                }

                foreach($toBeDeletedKeys as $toBeDeletedKey)
                {
                    //DELETE
                    $agendaI->deleteAgendaItem($dbValues['agendaid'][$toBeDeletedKey]);
                    dump('DELETE');
                }
            }
            else 
            { 
                //Normal, non repeating event
                //INSERT
                if(!empty($agendaItem) && is_numeric($agendaItem->id))
                {
                    $agendaI->setAgendaItemValue('id',$agendaItem->id);
                }

                $agendaId = $agendaI->saveAgendaItem();
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than implementing your checks in PHP, you can define a `UNIQUE` index across the `startdatum`, `stopdatum` and `herhalen dag van de week` columns; then use `REPLACE` with your `LOAD DATA` command to replace any existing record that matches on those fields with the new one:

```sql
ALTER TABLE events ADD UNIQUE INDEX (startdatum, stopdatum, dag);

LOAD DATA INFILE '/path/to/foo.csv'
  REPLACE
  INTO TABLE events;
```

Comment: Aye useful, but this does not solve my delete problem? (Or I'm not getting it) I need to check if the records in the DB are the same as in the .csv. If the csv does not have a record that the DB has I need to delete it from the DB

Comment: @Bono: OH.  Now I understand!  Why not `TRUNCATE TABLE events` before performing your `LOAD DATA`?

Comment: Thanks, I'll look in to that ;)

Comment: @Bono: To be clear, that will delete all entries from `events` and then load into the table the contents of the CSV; so the table ultimately holds only what is in the latest CSV and nothing else.  Is that what you were after?

Comment: No, that's roughly what I'm doing now. I just want to check for certain records. Thanks though ;) There are also possibilities to use multiple CSV's so deleting all entries from events would not beneficial :P

Comment: @Bono: Then I'm confused.  How does one know whether a database record *for which there is no corresponding entry in the latest CSV* is to be deleted or retained?

Comment: I'm comparing each db record external_id with each records external_id in the csv, if there is a DB record (date) which does not correspond to the csv record (date) it gets deleted. But yeah I'm getting confused too :P